# Errors when passing array by value in C, using a callback implementation

Tags: c, callback, pass-by-value

My program includes three files: main.c, app.c and callbk_struct.h

The function "get_data" in main.c makes callbacks to a function in app.c, which returns an array of integers.

When I print the array in "get_data", using "printf", everything seems to be fine.

But if I try to pass the array to another function, in this case the function "print_buffer" or "sizeof", something weird happens. I usually don't get problems when passing arrays between functions like this...

Could someone explain what is going on here?

See my program below:

callbk_struct.h

```
struct callback_struct{
    int * (*ptr_data)(void);
};

extern struct callback_struct user_functions; // is defined in app.c
```

app.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbk_struct.h"

int* my_data(void);

struct callback_struct user_functions={

        .ptr_data = my_data,
};


int* my_data(void){

 int i;

 // create some test data
     int N = 15; 
     int data[N];
     for(i=0; i<N; i++){
         data[i] = i;
      }

return data; 

}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbk_struct.h"

#define MAX_DATA 15

void print_buffer(int *data){

     int i;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_DATA; i++){
    printf(" %d ", data[i]);    
    }

 }

void get_data(int* (*ptr)(void)){

 int *data = ptr();


 // If I try to print the values directly with printf, I get the right values

            printf("Data from app.c %d %d %d", data[0], data[1], data[2]);

 //If I try to get the number of elements in the array, I get weird values..

            int data_size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int); 

// If I try to print the array, via this function,  I get weird values..

         print_buffer(data); 

}


 int main(void){

  get_data(user_functions.ptr_data);

  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: You can't pass an array by value, and you can't return a pointer to a local variable from within a function.

Comment: Aside: `int data_size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int)` is simple the size of a pointer (e.g. 2,4,8) divided by sizeof(int) (also 2, 4 or 8).  This is certainly _not_ the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

The weird values are caused by returning from `my_data` the local array, which ceases to exist when the value is returned from the function, so the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: Thank you @WojtekSurowka. Do you have any suggestion on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: One way is to allocate your array with `malloc` rather than making it an auto array.  Then you have to remember to call `free` on it when you're done.

Comment: Another way is to create the array outside of the function, pass in as a parameter a pointer to the array and a length.  Don't return it, just act upon the array pointed to by the parameter pointer.

Comment: Do not use functions returning a pointer, use functions filling a pointer passed as argument. So instead of `int* my_data(void)` use `void my_data(int* arr,unsigned length)`. Then you can declare your array in get_data and pass it to ptr.